# MPAndroidChart, How to apply animations that look like they're being drawn?

Tags: java, android, android-animation, mpandroidchart

If I apply the animation provided in MPAndroidChart library using the source below, the animation will look as if it were in the picture.

The animation seems to be cut off.
I want to apply an animation that looks like the chart is growing on the X-axis.

```
chart.animateX(1000);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: May be your x data streaming is cutting when reaching to 6.Could you check all of your data for existing of data(x data) until the end.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I don't understand what you mean. ;(

Comment: can you set code for LineDataSet